# Is there a way of reading the data out of a MATLAB's ".fig" file in Mathematica?

Tags: import, matlab

I have a ".fig" file from MATLAB that I know is a list of $ (x, y) $ coordinates. As far as I know, the ".fig" format stores the data and recreates it every time is opened. I would like to get the data in *Mathematica*.

`Import` says "Cannot infer format of file".
`Read` says "Invalid input found when reading MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file".

Comment: `BinaryReadList[file]` will allow you to import the binary of the file, but .fig files are not in plain text. I think you would have to know what encoding Mathworks used to create their file format.

Comment: do you have access to Matlab itself (or Octave?)

Comment: @Nasser Not now, but I could install Octave if needed.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/24656-open-fig-file-but-not-with-matlab

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format/ "FIGs are simply MATs in disguise"  Mathematica has _some_ support for old versions of the MAT format. The newest version is HDF5-based, and Mathematica can read H5 too. So there is hope. But it will take time to figure everything out.

Comment: @Nasser Seems that Octave won't help in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9269718/1551513

Comment: @Alan Then it seems it is not possible now and it will not be until "fig" format is reversed engineered. Thanks!